# Twine Sugarcube, limiting player stats

Tags: variables, limit, twine-game-engine, sugarcube

First of all I'm quite new to Twine and Sugarcube but I've found my way until now but now I've been struggling to find and answer to the below issue:

I have a character that has several stats like strength and energy.

I use them like this:

In the StoryInit:

```
<<set $energy to 100>>
```

In the passages of the story:

```
<<set $energy to $energy +10>>
```

Now I want to set a maximum and a minimum for all the stats seperately.
I used to do it like this:

```
<<set $energy to $energy +30>>
<<if $energy gte 100>><<set $energy to 100>>
<</if>>
```

But to this every time is a lot of work and and just asking for mistakes.

Is there and what is the best way to limit these stats seperately.
(so strength has a max of 200 and energy a max of 100)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Twine for a while but I think you can just use javascript Math stuff as normal:

```
<<set $energy to Math.clamp($energy + 30, 0, 100)>>
```

Or make it into a widget:

```
<<widget setEnergy>>
<<set $energy to Math.clamp($energy + $args[0], 0, 100)>>
<</widget>>
```

So you can use:

```
<<setEnergy +30>>
```

So you can avoid repetition/mistakes as you say. Make a similar one for strength etc. and just change the 100.